# Using RecordStore in Java J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, midp, rms

I am currently doing some J2ME development. I am having a problem in that a user can add and remove elements to the record store, and if a record gets deleted, then that record is left empty and the others don't move up one. I'm trying to come up with a loop that will check if a record has anything in it (incase it has been deleted) and if it does then I want to add the contents of that record to a list.
My code is similar to as follows:

```
      for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getNumRecords(); i++)
      {
        // Re-allocate if necessary

        if (rs.getRecordSize(i) > recData.length)
          recData = new byte[rs.getRecordSize(i)];
        len = rs.getRecord(i, recData, 0);
        st = new String(recData, 0, len);
        System.out.println("Record #" + i + ": " + new String(recData, 0, len));
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        if(st != null)
        {
            list.insert(i-1, st, null);
        }

      }
```

When it gets to rs.getRecordSize(i), I always get a "javax.microedition.rms.InvalidRecordIDException: error finding record". I know this is due to the record being empty but I can't think of a way to get around this problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 7 questions, 0 accepted answers and 0 votes. That doesn't look good.

Answer (score 6):

You should use a RecordEnumeration to visit the records:

```
RecordEnumeration renum = rs.enumerateRecords(null, null, false);
while (renum.hasNextElement())
{
    int index = renum.nextRecordId();
    if (store.getRecordSize(index) == STORE_LEN)
    {

    }
}
```

You can't rely on the recordId for anything useful. Use a different technique to reallocate a deleted record.

Comment: It is the length of the record. Your application should know about it. I use it to differentiate between different records. Of course you don't have to do the same. The idea is that you use the enumeration, get the index with nextRecordId and then the size with getRecordSize.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have your records *truly* deleted you have to close de RecordStore. The correct way to operate a RecordStore is by opening it, using it an finally closing it. Hope this is usefull to you

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the following method:

```
 /**
 * checks if record i is a valid records
 * @param i (recordId
 * @return true/false
 */
public boolean isValidRecord(int id) {

    try {
        recordStore.getRecordSize(id);
        return true;
    } catch (RecordStoreNotOpenException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (InvalidRecordIDException e1) {
        //e1.printStackTrace(); //this printStackTrace is hidden on purpose: the error is in fact used to find out if the record id is valid or not.
        return false;
    } catch (RecordStoreException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

}
```